# Is "Process.Close()" necessary?

Tags: c#, .net, process

when i am using process:

```
var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\cxecute.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

process.Start();
```

is it necessary to use process.close?

Comment: It depends....on what you define necessary

Comment: I think, this question for you. If it necessary, you must close, otherwise the process will live by its life.

Comment: The documentation says that [``Process.Close()``](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx) will free up the resources

Answer (score 4):

The `Process` type does contain resources it frees on calls to `Close` and it implements `IDisposable`.  Hence it should be treated like any other `IDisposable` object and have `Dispose` called when you are done using it.

Failing to call `Dispose` won't cause any direct issues with the use of the `Process` object though.  It's not like `FileStream` where failing to call `Close` can prevent other `FileStream` instances over the same file.  That being said, you should still call `Close` when you are done with it.

Comment: assuming the process is a win form, what will be the influence of 'process.close'?

Comment: @AssafZigdon nothing. It won't stop the process in question.  It just closes the resources in your app.

Comment: is it ok to leave my code without process.close or process.dispose?

Answer (score 0):

Process implements `IDisposable`. It is better to `Free resource` allocated by the Process.

`Process.Close()` - Frees all the resources that are associated with this component.

So yes if the process must be `Closed/Disposed`

Comment: assuming the process is a win form, what will be the influence of 'process.close'?

Comment: as `JaredPar` said : `Failing to call Close won't cause any direct issues with the use of the Process object though. `